# RestKit: Map Local to-many relationship to JSON array of object ids

Tags: ios, json, mapping, restkit, relationship

Another RestKit mapping problem for the boards:

Locally I have Core Data objects Group and Message; a Group has many Messages and a Message can have many Groups that it's sent to. I need to map the relationship of Messages to Groups (groups) into a JSON array (group_ids) of just the Group id's (id_number) to send to. Essentially I need my request JSON to look like this:

```
{
message:{
   ... // Other message data
   group_ids:[
       1208,
       93,
       ...
   ]
   ...
}
}
```

The closet thing I've come up with that naturally doesn't work is:

```
RKObjectMapping *messageMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[messageMapping addAttributesFromDictionary:@{ @"body":@"body" }];

RKObjectMapping *groupIdMapping = [RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[groupIdMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKAttributeMappingFromKeyPath:@"id_number" toKeyPath:nil];

[messageMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"groups" toKeyPath:@"group_ids" withMapping:groupIdMapping];
```

Unfortunately this yields the result in the log:

```
Mapped relationship object from keyPath 'groups' to 'group_ids'. Value: (
  {
    1208 = {};
  }
)
```

Which makes a small amount of sense to me, but I don't know how else to approach solving this mapping. I'm hoping it's a simple solution I just haven't come across yet. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I accomplished this by NOT creating a mapping for this particular case, and instead just constructing the parameter dictionary with the required message data to pass to `[RKObjectManager postObject:path:parameters:success:failure]` Worked as intended for our API, but I'd still be interested in how to accomplish the mapping described if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
[messageMapping addAttributesFromDictionary:@{ @"body":@"body", @"groups.id_number":@"group_ids" }];
```

Which should hopefully use the keypath capability to create an array if the relationship content values.